# Python SMTPLIB with proxy support, Gmail connection not allowed

Tags: python, proxy, smtplib

I am succesfully sending emails through gmail app password, python and smtplib.

I am attempting to add proxy support to my script, but I am getting hit by the following error message:

```
socks.GeneralProxyError: Socket error: 0x02: Connection not allowed by ruleset
```

Here are the relevant parts of my script:

```
socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, host, port, True, user, passw)
socks.wrapmodule(smtplib)

session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
session.login(sender_address, sender_pass)
```

Comment: Have you already reviewed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29200802/2055998)?

Comment: Yup, that question is about .onion sites, something totally different and I don't think the answer applies.